CSS Paged media: Can I make one column shorter than the others?
I'm working on a page that has 4 columns. I want to make the last column slightly shorter so I can insert a logo in the bottom right corner of the page.

I tried putting the logo in a running footer element. The text in the column will flow through the logo area, overlapping the logo, and I don't want that.
I also tried putting the logo into an element with position: fixed. Same result: the text will overlap the logo.
Is there a way to make the last column shorter than the others? I don't want to shorten all columns because this is a fixed-size layout (content has to fit on one page) and we need all the space for text we can get.
I'm using Antennahouse Formatter 7.3.

You could try including the logo in the content and floating it to the bottom-right corner. Untested, but something like -ah-float: bottom right multicol;.
See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-float.html

I tried using a float, but I had the logo end up in the last column that contained text, instead of the 4th column. Adding multicol solves that.
